# MS Teams video effects does not show options

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, microsoft-teams

MS teams video effects show circling forever on Macbook Pro (M2) MacOS 13.0.1.

> Microsoft Teams Version 1.6.00.19353. It was last updated on 23/03/2023.

[image]

Please advise how to fix.

Comment: First thing to do would be update macOS to the current version. 13.0.1 was as buggy as all heck. Current version is 13.5